# The edit preview screen in the iOS app only shows the top inch of the post's text

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, ios-app, markdown-preview

After editing a post in the iOS app, the final preview window shows only about an inch of text below the title, rather than the complete post. This began when I downloaded the iOS app version 1.4.0.243, so I'm wondering if it's a bug. I'm using an iPad 2 running iOS 9.1. It happens on questions and answers, with and without pictures, and on a variety of SE sites.

The top row of my pictures show the original question, then the edit screen after editing. Below that on the left is the edit preview, with the finished version after submission next to it. Click on them for full-screen views.

[image: question]           [image: during edit]

[image: edited preview]     [image: after edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in 1.4.0.244.

I reworked some stuff about post resizing to improve the scrolling experience and forgot to connect it to the preview screens.

Comment: Thanks very much Brian, but now I can't open the app! Every time I select the icon, it opens for less than a second, then closes back to my iPad home screen.  I can tell it's trying, so I feel sad for it  :)

Comment: @Sue :( I'll debug in the morning.

Comment: No problem! Have a good night!

Comment: @Sue You should be able to download again.  We had an expired provisioning profile.

Comment: Hi Brian! Thanks for explaining what went wrong. I like learning things, so I'll look that up.  Unfortunately I still can't open it! I checked to see if I could get it from the app store instead, but that version is 1.4.0, dated September 24. Do you have a link I can plug into Safari so I can update my usual way? Thanks!

Comment: I'll send you an email.

Comment: Got it, thanks. It's much better, with very complete and pretty previews! Strangely, with some questions, the app just closes when I ask it for the preview. So far it's happened with two questions, both on the same site, Seasoned Advice. I've tried it on a number of sites and can't replicate. Unless there's a reason for that which makes sense to you, I'll do some research into different variables and update the report later. I'll start with a re-boot, which might solve the whole problem!!

Comment: I'm sorry to say the reboot didn't help. It doesn't happen every time, but on a number of both questions and answers, at various sites, choosing the edit preview causes the app to close. Since I now have 1.4.0.249, and it's not the bug reported in this question, should I just submit a new bug report? Thanks!

Comment: @Sue definitely. I saw it once too.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270125/the-ios-app-intermittently-closes-when-attempting-to-view-an-edit-preview) you go! Let me know if you need more details. Thanks!