# The iOS app intermittently closes when attempting to view an edit preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, ios-app

In an edit window, choosing "Tap here to see the final preview" causes the SE iOS app to close. Sometimes, but not always, there's a very brief white screen with the word Preview on top. It doesn't last long enough to take a screenshot.

The issue is frequent but random, occurring either a number of times in a row, or not until after a very few successful edits. I've encountered it:

- on five different sites, including here on meta.
- on both questions and answers, regardless of their length or presence of pictures or formatting.
- during edits of any number of characters.
- with or without changing any text on the site where I have full edit privileges.

It occurs whether or not I have other apps open. Re-booting doesn't help.

Because it's intermittent, I don't know if it's version specific, but for me it began immediately after installation of version 1.4.0.249. I have not changed anything on my device, which is iPad 2 running iOS 9.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in 1.4.0.250.

The issue comes from some weird code and a bad assumption on my part.  When we show a normal question and answer page, we use a `SEQuestionAndAnswerViewController` with its data backed by a `SEQuestionStore`.  For simplicity's sake, full question and answer previews use much of the same code as `SEQuestionAndAnswerViewController` (via a shared superclass `SEPostViewController`), including the `SEQuestionStore`.

This last part is important, because `SEQuestionStore` only deals in term of [questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) while previews can be in terms of [answers](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer), [suggested edits](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/suggested-edit), or just the extremely light-weight question responses from [/questions/render](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/render-question).  As such, basic shell models are often created to shoehorn these models into questions and this leads to a question or answer sometimes missing an `owner` field.

*So, why is this suddenly crashing?*

We have a not-yet-formally-announced-but-I'm-really-excited-about-it feature going into the iOS app which is very interested in the user IDs that will be displayed on a post.  As such, when we load a question in `SEQuestionStore`, it collects the user IDs with the following line:

```
NSSet<NSNumber *> *userIds = [[[BITE(@[question]) and:question.answers] mapWithKeyPath:@"owner.userId"] set];
```

This code uses my [bite-objc](https://github.com/bnickel/bite-objc) functional enumerator library to create an enumerator of the question and answers (posts), map it to the owner user id and convert it to a set.  Bite heavily leverages the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol which unlike Foundation collections has no issue with `nil` entities, meaning that if we make a fake question to wrap a newly returned answer and `question.owner == nil`, we end up with an enumerator of `(nil, 272239)`.  When we build the set and add `nil` to it, the app crashes.

The solution is to filter `nil` out of the enumerator before converting to the set:

```
NSSet<NSNumber *> *userIds = [[[[BITE(@[question]) and:question.answers] mapWithKeyPath:@"owner.userId"] filterWithFormat:@"self != nil"] set];
```

The funny thing is, I wrote most of this new feature in Swift because I absolutely didn't want it to break on runtime stuff like this. I guess I should have written this method in Swift with a signature like `preloadWithQuestion(_:SEAPIQuestion, site:SEAPISite)`

Comment: No doubt a candidate for the most detailed fix report ever. ;)

Comment: I have to agree. This is like going to a programming class for free! I've spent the last hour trying very hard to re-create the problem, and I can't, so thanks for the education and the fix!

Comment: Way off topic but while I have you... Would you kindly tell me how to discard my edits in progress, of which there are now many! I'm sure it's something simple that I just can't find. Thanks!